# distinct values from graphql nested arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have GraphQL results like below that I'm trying to process in javascript

```
{
  "data": {
    "shoeStyleColor": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "shoeInventories": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "qty": 2,
            "size": 6.5
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "qty": 2,
            "size": 9
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "shoeInventories": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "qty": 3,
            "size": 8
          },
          {
            "id": 6,
            "qty": 1,
            "size": 9
          }
        ],
      }  
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to get a distinct list of sizes like this... [6.5,8,9]

```
[...new Set(products.data.shoeStyleColor.map(x => x.shoeInventories.map(y => y.size)))]
```

but it get something like this
[6.5,9],[8,9]

Once I have that, I want to filter the entire array by a selected size, say 9... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const products = {"data":{"shoeStyleColor":[{"id":1,"shoeInventories":[{"id":1,"qty":2,"size":6.5},{"id":2,"qty":2,"size":9}]},{"id":2,"shoeInventories":[{"id":5,"qty":3,"size":8},{"id":6,"qty":1,"size":9}]}]}}

const result = [...new Set(products.data.shoeStyleColor.flatMap(x => x.shoeInventories.map(y => y.size)))]    

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Excellent that works great. now I want to filter the array based on a selection of size and color..
const products = {"data":{"shoeStyleColor":[{"id":1,"shoeColor": {"description": "Black"},"shoeInventories":[{"id":1,"qty":2,"size":6.5},{"id":2,"qty":2,"size":9}]},{"id":2,"shoeInventories":[{"id":5,"qty":3,"size":8},{"id":6,"qty":1,"size":9}]}]}}
products.data.shoeStyleColor.filter(function(item) {
    if ((item.shoeColor.description === "Brown") &&
       (item.shoeInventories.size === 4.5)) {return true}
      else {return false}
  } )

doesn't work.

Comment: Figured it out!  
filteredProducts =  products.data.shoeStyleColor.filter(function(item) {
    if ((item.shoeColor.description === "Brown") &&
      (item.shoeInventories.find(o => o.size === 6.5)))
       {return true}
      else {return false}
  } )